# Issue on removal of joint js node on click of its custom html click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, jointjs

I am using joint.js in my angular.js application , I have joint.js node in which I am using html

```
<button class="delete">x</button>
```

( you can see this in my backbone view template) whenever user clicks on this button, I want to remove the node which works absolutely fine but what I want to improve is that button should appear only when user clicks on its node and when user clicks on paper other than node that cross button should disappear just like

http://jointjs.com/rappid#a3e927c4-9c6b-4159-b14e-920299be8f87

my logic which I thought is to have  a class in button's parent div

```
    .html-element button.delete{
        display: none;
    }
    .html-element.showButton button.delete{
       display: block;
    }
```

which will be added when user will click on the node and removed when user will click on the paper. but when I do this logic of adding and removing class it works but the functionality of removal of node on cross button stops.

By whole day debugging and altering the code, I have come to this ,that somehow when this function is called

```
   f2:function(){
                     var self=this;
                     var elementDiv = $(self.$box).find('button');
                     elementDiv.parent().removeClass("showButton")
              }
```

the removal of node on cross button click stops.it means the binding of icon to removal function of model is removed. this is the binding

```
this.$box.find('.delete').on('click', function()
                    self.model.remove();
                });
```

I hope that this explanation makes some sense. Below is complete code

```
   var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;
    var element1=false;
    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#workFlow'),
        width: '100%',
        height: '98%',
        model: graph,
        gridSize: 1
    });
    paper.on('cell:pointerdown',
        function(cellView, evt, x, y) {
            $scope.cellView=cellView;
            cellView.f1();
        }
    );
    paper.on('blank:pointerdown', function(cell) {
      $scope.cellView.f2();
    });
```

Backbone View for extending shapes

```
 joint.shapes.html = {};
        joint.shapes.html.Element = joint.shapes.basic.Rect.extend({
            defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
                type: 'html.Element',
                attrs: {
                    rect: { stroke: 'none', 'fill-opacity': 0,stageType: dataSourceType}
                }
            }, joint.shapes.basic.Rect.prototype.defaults)
        });
```

// Create a custom view for that element that displays an HTML div above it.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
joint.shapes.html.ElementView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({

    template: [

            '<span class="glyphicons '+icon+' html-element">',
        '<button class="delete">x</button>',
        '</span>'

    ].join(''),

    initialize: function() {
        var self=this;
        _.bindAll(this, 'updateBox');
        joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.$box = $(_.template(this.template)());
        //  this.$box.find('.delete').on('click', _.bind(this.model.remove, this.model));
        this.$box.find('.delete').on('click', function(event){
            self.model.remove();
        });
        // Update the box position whenever the underlying model changes.
        this.model.on('change', this.updateBox, this);
        // Remove the box when the model gets removed from the graph.
        this.model.on('remove', this.removeBox, this);
        this.updateBox();
    }
    ,
    render: function() {
        var self=this;
        joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
        this.paper.$el.prepend(this.$box);
        this.updateBox();
        return this;
    },

    updateBox: function() {
        // Set the position and dimension of the box so that it covers the JointJS element.
        var bbox = this.model.getBBox();
        // Example of updating the HTML with a data stored in the cell model.
        this.$box.css({ width: bbox.width, height: bbox.height, left: bbox.x, top: bbox.y, transform: 'rotate(' + (this.model.get('angle') || 0) + 'deg)' });
    },
    removeBox: function(evt) {
        this.$box.remove();
    },
    f1:function(){
        var self=this;
        var elementDiv = $(self.$box).find('button');
        elementDiv.parent().addClass("showButton");
    },
    f2:function(){
        var self=this;
        var elementDiv = $(self.$box).find('button');
        elementDiv.parent().removeClass("showButton")

    }
});

var el1 = new joint.shapes.html.Element({ position: { x: $scope.shapeX, y: $scope.shapeY }, size: { width: 40, height: 40 }, label: 'I am HTML', select: 'one' });
graph.addCells([el1]);
```

Comment: is it so difficult to understand?? any one going to answer??

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't solved your problem: there is a very simple solution for what you want to do. You just need to use the hover function in css styling and change the opacity from 0 to 1 when you hover over the box (in your css file) :

```
.html-element button.delete {
   color: white;
   border: none;
   background-color: gray;
   border-radius: 20px;
   width: 15px;
   height: 15px;
   line-height: 15px;
   text-align: middle;
   position: absolute;
   top: -5px;
   left: -5px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   font-weight: bold;
   cursor: pointer;
   opacity:0;
}
.html-element button.delete:hover {
   /*width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 20px;*/
   opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for looking into my question... I have already tried your solution it does work...but the thing is it still remains in the dom even if its opacity is 0 so if user accidentally clicks on that area the element will be removed... even if cross sign is not showing.